# Printer stops printing at the same spot for every model

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, pla, z-axis

The 3D printer I'm using (Creality Ender 3 v2) stops printing at approximately the same height and no matter which model I try to print. When it stops, it does not go to park position or auto home, it just stops and sits on top of the print (getting stuck to it). It just started happening out of the blue, I have printed multiple things before this.

[image: This is how the printer stops, stuck to the print]

I am using the Creality Ender 3 v2, printing PLA at a temperature of 200 °C with the print bed at 70 °C. The Z-axis of the printer woks just fine manually. I changed the nozzle and I've made sure it is not clogged. The firmware does not need to be updated, and the bed is level.

I do not know what else the reason could be. Would love to hear your thoughts and opinions on why this is happening. Here's an image of what the print looks like:

[image: The dot is the spot where the printer stopped working and just got stuck there until I manually moved it]

And this is the g-code info from the little I understand about it

[image: g-code]

Comment: Hi CK, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Is this a brand new printer and has this always happened, or did this develop lately and now present in every model? Maybe linking to the G-code file (to e.g. Pastebin.com) could help us help you. Could be a faulty modifier in your start G-code. Which slicer do you use?

Comment: @oscar, Hi! This is a pretty new printer. Someone else set it up before me and I've just been printing on it since. We've printed about 3-4 models with no glaring issues, until the printer randomly stopped. I have been using the creality slicer. How can I get the G-code file to you? I have never shared it before

Comment: When you slice an object, you can save the file, please post this .gcode file on Pastebin.com for instance.

Comment: This could be a truncated gcode file, as a result of a corrupted SD card or trying to save the gcode on a full disk (at least in certain configurations, some slicers fail to report an error on writing to a full disk).

Comment: @oscar So, I opened the gcode in a text editor. Copied the text, pasted it on pastebin.com and tried to share it but it says that the code is too big. Sorry if these questions are stupid. I have never done this before. Can I put the code over 2 links on pastebin?

Comment: @R.. GitHub I reformatted the SD card and it seems to be working now. Thanx!

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Please add an answer on the SD card issue, it seems to have fixed the issue. CKPrintissues, please accept that answer when posted. My own experience with SD cards is that is I save to SD card directly from Cura, the print fails, but if saved to HD first and copied to SD it works...

Answer (score 6):

This behavior can be explained by a truncated gcode file - the printer gets to the end of all that's there of the file, and considers it done. A truncated file can be a symptom of corrupt storage media (corrupt SD card), or trying to save a file to a disk that's full with software that ignores the "disk full" error. At least in certain configurations, some slicers fail to report an error on writing to a full disk; I've had this happen when using Cura from the command line rather than the GUI.

Backing up any important data from the SD card then reformatting it is a good first step to try, and seems to have solved the problem for OP.